# Make multiple File Upload with their respective fields using PNP JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload, pnp, pnp-js-core

I have a picture library with 4-5 fields - Lets Take - Title(string), Date(Date), FlagOn(Boolean).

I am trying to upload 10 files to my picture library and for all these 10 files i want the same metadata values (Field values) which i enter in a form when i make the upload

I want to complete this with PnP JS.

Any help please ?